# how can i access django with apache? apache showing default page on django

Tags: python, django, apache

i am getting the default page of apache2 when i try to access the django on my lan ip address via apache server. i am also running django `python manage.py runsever` command and try to access with `192.168.10.11`. but it still showing the default page of apache.
how can i access django with apache?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /home/five/NewsDesk/server
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/five/NewsDesk/server/server/wsgi.py

 # adjust the following line to match your Python path 
 WSGIDaemonProcess 192.168.10.11 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/five/NewsDesk/env/lib/python3.8
 WSGIProcessGroup 192.168.10.11

 <directory /home/five/NewsDesk/server>
   <Files wsgi.py>
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
   </Files>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /home/five/NewsDesk/server/staticfiles/

 <Directory /home/five/NewsDesk/server/staticfiles>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`apache2ctl -S`

```
$apache2ctl -S

VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/newsdesk.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: Your `WSGIScriptAlias` is `/NewsDesk` - if you want it to be the root of the site, try changing it to just `/`?

Comment: i also try with `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/five/NewsDesk/server/server/wsgi.py` this code but am getting same issue apache default page render....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess, your `django` project should have the following structure :

```
. home
  .. five
     .. NewsDesk
        .. server #  Your Django project root folder
           .. server
              .. settings.py
              .. wsgi.py

           ..

           .. staticfiles #  Your public folder to collect assets (js, css, img ..)
                          #  and served using apache

           .. manage.py
```

to serve/expose your `django` project **locally** using `apache` server you need to make some changes on:

## vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # ServerName localhost
  ServerName myapp.local  #  rename your server

  DocumentRoot /home/five/NewsDesk/server
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/five/NewsDesk/server/server/wsgi.py
  
  # adjust the following line to match your Python path 

  # i intentionnally commented the 2 lines below
  # WSGIDaemonProcess 192.168.10.11 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/five/NewsDesk/env/lib/python3.8
  # WSGIProcessGroup 192.168.10.11
  
  <directory /home/five/NewsDesk/server/server>  # HERE a missing "/server"
    <Files wsgi.py>
      # Allow from all
      Require all granted
    </Files>
    # AllowOverride all
    # Require all granted
    # Options FollowSymlinks
  </directory>
  
  Alias /static /home/five/NewsDesk/server/staticfiles  # HERE remove the triailling "/"
  <Directory /home/five/NewsDesk/server/staticfiles>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

## /etc/hosts

(depending on `linux` distro and how `apache` is installed and configured)

```
127.0.0.1  myapp.local
```

## settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
  '127.0.0.1', 'localhost',
  '192.168.10.11', 'myapp.local',
]
```

and now, to expose your app locally, use the command below

```
python manage.py runserver YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:PORT
```

but in your case, it should be :

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.10.11
```

let me know if this was useful for you